# Set field multivalued = false

Tags: solr

When I execute a query with an order clause, the system throws an exception like this

> cannot sort on multivalued field: DATE".

this occurs with all fields types like string, long, etc.

I analysed the fields with the Solr Schema Browser and all the fields have *multivalue=true;* for the flags "properties" and "schema". (image atached[image])

I'm inserting the documents in this way whith java code:

```java
        String solrPath = Configuration.getString("solr.path");
        HttpSolrClient solr = new HttpSolrClient(solrPath);
        SolrInputDocument document = new SolrInputDocument();
        document.addField("CATEGORY", knowError.getCategory().getDescription());
        document.addField("RAITING", knowError.getRaiting()); //long value
        document.addField("DATE", knowError.getRevisionDate());                      
        UpdateRequest req = new UpdateRequest();
        req.setAction(UpdateRequest.ACTION.COMMIT, false, false);
        req.add(document);
        UpdateResponse response = req.process(solr);
        solr.commit();
```

And I make the querys in this way:

```java
        String solrPath = Configuration.getString("solr.path");
        HttpSolrClient client = new HttpSolrClient(solrPath);
        client.setUseMultiPartPost(true);
        client.setConnectionTimeout(5000);
        SolrQuery solrQuery = new SolrQuery();
        solrQuery.setQuery(key);
        solrQuery.setFields("KEDB_ID", "CAUSE", "SOLUTION", "WORKAROUND", "CATEGORY","DESCRIPTION","AUTHOR","TAGS","RAITING","DATE");
        solrQuery.setStart(0);
        solrQuery.setRows(200);
        if(filterByRaiting){   
            solrQuery.addSort("RAITING", SolrQuery.ORDER.desc);
        }else (filterByDate)
        {
            solrQuery.addSort("DATE", SolrQuery.ORDER.desc);
        }     
        //solrQuery.addSort(SolrQuery.SortClause.asc("CAUSE"));
        QueryResponse response = client.query(solrQuery);
        ret= response.getResults();
```

How can I make the fields *multivalue=false* in the inserts?

Comment: Do you know where your **schema.xml** is located? These kinds of settings are done there. Afterwards you are required to re-index.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can define some `dynamic fields` in your schema file before, like

`<dynamicField name="*_i" type="slong" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />`

and inserting the documents in this way whith java code:

`document.addField("RAITING_i", knowError.getRaiting()); //long value`